# How to Read Mifare Card Web Based

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mifare

I have some card readers that can read mifare card. This card readers plug to USB or COM port of PC. For read this cards in a c# windows application, i put a timer on the form and in the tick event of this timer i read the card serial number and do another opertaion based on card serial number.

Now i want to use this card readers in a asp.net or asp.net mvc web based application. some card readers have a characteristic that when there are a text box in the web page that focused on it, and user put card on the card reader the serial number of card put in this text box. but some else don't have this characteristic. so i want to write an event for all card readers that i have that when card put on the card reader an event occur and card read by java script or jquery and send an AJAX request to the server so that card serial number send via this request.

In other words, i require an jQuery of Java Script Based Event that can read mifare cards and it's serial number. this solution must work in any browser. in IE there are activeX. what about other browsers?

i find [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/GaretJax/CardReader/blob/master/CardReader.js) that works for magnetic stripe cards , but i want a solution for mifare cards.